# Limit SQL when I can, or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have many queries I know should return 1 or 2 results. Should I explicitly LIMIT them or just let the DB do his job?
The scenario I mean is I am WHEREing on a unique combination of keys, OR when I might have the same result many times, just do LIMIT 1 instead of using DISTINCT...

Comment: An explicit `LIMIT` typically helps performance because the engine will stop returning rows.

Comment: Might doing so mask a bug that could exist in the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to limit the number of rows accessed as a smaller result set runs faster.

An excerpt from SQL Server's* Query Performance Tuning:

> Queries should request a relatively small number of rows. For example, search engines on the Web mostly return a limited number of articles at a time, even if the search criteria returns thousands of matching articles. If the queries request a large number of rows, the increased overhead cost of a lookup makes the index less suitable.

Alternatively, you can create a highly selective criteria:

> A filter criterion with high selectivity limits the number of rows from a table to a small result set and helps the optimizer keep the query cost low.

**I know question is tagged as MySQL*

Answer (score 5):

If you *know* they should return 1 or 2 rows, then adding `LIMIT` means you are hiding an issue if they return more than 1 or two rows. This is the equivalent to swallowing exceptions by wrapping your code like this:

```
try{
    //some code
} 
catch{
    //do nothing
}
```

So, I would not use `LIMIT` in this case. Instead, I would throw an error in the application layer when this occurs (or log it, etc.).

Comment: Use `LIMIT` when you need it. `LIMIT` is different than `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an error for the queries to return more than that number of results and knowing this is important to the application, you need to throw an exception if there are more results than expected.

Related to this, having unbounded queries can be detrimental to the performance of the application and the SQL database - if a result set that is expected to have only 1 or 2 values ends up having thousands, you could be in trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I use `LIMIT` for two reasons:

1. To return a known quantity of rows from a larger set (top 5 users, from X users)
2. To keep me from `DELETE`ing more records than I expect :)  And, in that case, I set the LIMIT to be one larger than I'm expecting, so it doesn't mask the error that @RedFilter describes.